# How to stop RAM test destroying its own variables embedded C?

Tags: c, testing, embedded, ram

During startup tests I am required to test all RAM locations using a galpat test, I have wrote the function to do this but run into a problem that the functions variables exist in RAM and therefore get mashed as part of the test.

What would be the best way around this?

Comment: Do the test before you set up a stack?

Comment: Run the test on the free portion of the memory. Copy the test code to the tested region, jump there and run again on the untested region.

Comment: Could you expand on this @EugeneSh. ? How exactly would I move the code?

Comment: No, I can't as it's rather complex, and too broad for comments or answers here, but certainly doable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Most embedded RAM tests run from ROM anyhow - So no need to move the code.

Comment: @tofro Well, at least the stack and data sections should be relocated. Of course you can try and write your code without even using them...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes sure - But you said "code"

Comment: @tofro I said "code" in general, as I am not making the assumption it will run from ROM.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: If the RAM is unreliable and your code is in RAM, how do you know that the test *really* was successful if it claims to have been?

Comment: @EOF and what if the device doesn't have an executable ROM at all?

Comment: @EugeneSh. How would such a device boot? You intend to toggle in the bootloader at a console?

Comment: @EOF Let me rephrase: "Executable *programmable* ROM.

Comment: Is it possible to set the variables use to specific RAM addresses and then have duplicate functions, each one checks the RAM the locations of the variables from the other function?

Comment: @EugeneSh. How would such a device execute the OP's code? Read the program from some kind of I/O (such as toggling it into a console like it's the 60's)?

Comment: @EOF Why? It is very common. There is some basic L0 boot code in the ROM, which is copying some L1 code from a predefined non-volatile storage to RAM and jumping there.

Comment: @nodee3345 You *could* have duplicate code, each checking the other's integrity, but unless you're running the two copies on two separate cpu-cores concurrently, how do you know that an error in the copy you executed first doesn't cause the second check to be bypassed?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I wouldn't know about "common". As far as I can tell, the usual way is to execute directly from flashrom, particularly since RAM tends to be scarce.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the input, unfortunately I'm lead down this path by requirements of standards - if I can meet the requirements I'm happy. I understand from reading around that there always seems to be pitfalls to whichever approach is used.

Comment: @EOF NAND flash is inherently non-executable, and it is rather common on embedded devices..

Comment: How would I move the addresses of the variables used around so that they are not destroyed?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There are systems which execute from NAND flash. But they use a buffer in the Flash-controller which does the ECC, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach could be - especially taking care of the processor stack, `.data` and `.bss` is something you can avoid - but there is no easy way to have C work without a proper stack:

- Write your code that it exclusively uses ROM code and stack variables.
- Have your startup code (that would normally be written in assembler anyhow) allocate the stack in the upper half of memory, test the lower half
- move (copy) the stack from upper memory to already tested areas (can be done in C)
- Reset the stack pointer to point to the copied stack (involves assembler coding)
- Do the rest of the memtest (can be done in C again)

(This assumes your code runs from ROM, which it would normally do at such early point in the start-up). In case there is any memory failure in areas where you allocate the stack, your code will simply crash (What it does *before that* - Reactor meltdown... - depends on the application).

When moving the stack around *outside C's control*, you should be very careful what you actually store there - Pointers to stack variables will become invalid - or rather undefined -  once you've moved the stack. Simple scalar variables and pointers to **outside the stack** as typically used in a RAM test should work, however.

You could try and declare your variables as `register` to try and keep RAM usage as low as possible - But you can't *force* C to put certain variables into registers, and a good C compiler will put them there anyhow.

Whether this is any better than writing the whole memtest in assembler (you'd need to do the stack adjustments in assembler anyhow, as there is no means to move the processor stack around in C) I dare to challenge. I don't see much of a point here using C on this low level, especially as assembler could run a memtest routine completely from registers, without using any RAM. This makes it much more immune to any RAM problem. A RAM testing routine shouldn't **rely on** working memory.

Comment: You can't generally copy the stack, because the stack can contain pointers to stack'ed objects. Also, the assertion that memory failures will simply cause crashes is questionable. On an embedded system (likely no memory protection), the code could easily do quite a bit of damage before it hardfaults. I'd second the advice to write a register-only assembly memcheck.

Comment: @EOF You're right, but: what the stack stores, is mainly up to you. If it stores pointers into the stack itself or other non-relocatable stuff - your fault. I was just trying to point out a method that has some potential that someone could make it work - I myself would never try and write such a low-level routine in C, also (and mainly) with respect to the second part of your comment. A memory-testing routine shouldn't *rely on* memory.

Comment: There might be no stack.

Comment: There might also be a meteor hitting your head. Roughly the same probability.

Comment: @tofro: You never used a PIC16, did you? That arch does not have a stack for variables and a good compiler will not use one. For other MCUs like HC08 there are similar options (they do have a stack, but some compilers allow not to use it for variables under unproblematic constraints).

Comment: Oh, and you should take the [tour] how to address a comment properly.

Comment: @Olaf - The PIC16 I know has a stack - Whether you consider it "RAM" that needs to be tested is debatable (And if you wanted to you'd obviously need to do that in a specific way different from what I described). In case the MCU can completely run from registers, it is unnecessary to save the stack. I think that should be obvious.

Comment: And whether a PIC16 would justify a RAM test at all is surely debatable as well.

Comment: @tofro: "That arch does not have a stack for **variables** ..." - Please read correctly. How abotu RTFM? And whether the RAM should be tested is a matter of the application. I have seen such requirements (if they make sense is a different matter, but that's the same for what OP asks. Things are just much more complicated than what you propose in your answer. That's why the question is far too broad..

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is you cannot, you have two choices, you can either only test part of the ram or part of the ram at a time which means you are not doing a complete address test.  Or you dont run from the ram you are testing, which is basically the rule if you really want to test the ram.  So you have to run from rom with out using a stack in the ram under test or you use another ram, perhaps there is a cache somewhere that can be used direct access to give you a little ram.

Testing half or some other fraction at a time, which is not a complete test, but better than not testing part of it at all, can be done with either a position independent module or with multiple compiles of the test that are position dependent.  No reason for the stack to be an issue, the rom based code copying and jumping to the code under test can set the stack pointer based on the fraction under test or not under test, and then repeat.  Treat the module like a function not like an entire program and the preserving the stack or "moving the test" problem goes away it returns back to the rom based code which can relaunch further tests.

One crazy way to do it would be to attempt to turn on the I cache get the test code into the cache (before it hits itself), and then blast away at the ram including the code behind the ram.  (cant have stack)  I would only try this as a fun experiment but not for anything real.  Lots of problems to solve with an approach like this.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be this:

1. Do the test before anything is initialized (variables, stack). In gcc you can: `void RAM_test(void) _attribute_ ((section (".init0")));`
2. Write it in assembly. Ensure that the test does not use/store any variables in the RAM, only uses processor registers.
3. Store the result somewhere so you can use it later in normal program.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have ROM space and can afford the time at boot time, I would implement the test in assembly or in a naked C function using directives to put your variables in registers so that no RAM is consumed as part of the test. This is going to be pretty architecture and compiler specific, though, and neither of those were mentioned.